# How to map two related JSONs using RestKit?

Tags: objective-c, magento, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have two JSONs, which are looking like:

```
{
    "749": {
        "email": "myMail@me.com",
        "firstname": "Mr",
        "lastname": "Smith"
    }
}
```

and

```
[
    {
        "entity_id": "1",
        "city": "myCity",
        "country_id": "UA",
        "region": null,
        "postcode": "001",
        "telephone": "+38000000001",
        "fax": null,
        "street": [
            "myStrit ",
            "12"
        ],
        "is_default_billing": 1,
        "is_default_shipping": 0
    },
    {
        "entity_id": "2",
        "city": "myCity",
        "country_id": "UA",
        "region": null,
        "postcode": "001",
        "telephone": "+3800000002",
        "fax": null,
        "street": [
            "myStrit2",
            "33"
        ],
        "is_default_billing": 0,
        "is_default_shipping": 1
    }
]
```

Path for getting first JSON is `mySite/customers`, and for the second is `mySite/customers/:userId/addresses`.

where `userId` is unnamed attribute from first JSON (749 in my example).

I am new in RestKit and I can't really figure out, how to map it by one request...

PS: I get these JSONs  from Magento rest api.

Comment: you can use RestKit examples for a start, before asking so general questions

Answer (score 0):

You say nothing about what you're trying to map into, but.

For the first JSON, you need to use [`addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectMapping.html#//api/name/addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute%3a) on the mapping to extract the `749` value and use it as a key at the same time.

For the second JSON there doesn't appear to be any connection to the first so you need to try mapping that and come back with specific issues. See [this page](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping) for guidance.

Comment: There is not a problem to map these JSONs separately. I have mapping first JSON using 'addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute', but what next? I can generate path for getting second JSON using mapping result of the first (all I need for it - is userID), but I need to do this for all customers and it will be long cycle. Is there  any way to do this more easier?

Comment: Show that code and ask that question - what you have asked so far is not the same thing. Why do you want to get all? Why not just get the currently selected one? Use a loop.

Comment: OK. It must have been some misunderstanding... I have JSON containing 100 customers (JSON 1). For each customer I can get JSON with their addresses (JSON 2) just using attribute custimerID from JSON 1 for generating  path to get JSON 2. But, for doing that, i have to loop 100 iteration and send 100 requests to server. I can't believe, that it is only one way to get collection of customers with their addresses. If customers and their addresses where in one JSON, it wouldn't be a problem, I could use RestKit mapping with relationships, but they are in separate JSONs and this make a problem.

Comment: That is a server problem and has nothing to do with RestKit. You need to find out if the server can be changed or makes another service available that you can use...

Comment: Yeah, I know that it's bad server logic, but it's result of standard Magento rest api service and i can't influence this... May be someone had practice on working with Magento rest api?

Answer (score 0):

RestKit expects each object to be described by a dictionary which can be processed by the mapper. Your service does not return an array of objects, though, rather a dictionary of dictionaries, which RestKit cannot correctly interpret as a collection of objects it can map individually. Of course, the problem would disappear if your service could return an array of dictionaries instead.

Fortunately, there is a way to transform the dictionary of dictionaries you receive into an array of dictionaries right before the mapper is called. This is achieved by setting a conversion block via `-[RKObjectRequestOperation setWillMapDeserializedResponseBlock:]`.

The block receives the result of the initial parsing (here the dictionary of dictionaries), which you can easily turn into an array of dictionaries by calling `-[NSDictionary allValues]`:

```
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = ...;
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = ...;
NSURLRequest *request = ...;

RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *managedObjectRequestOperation = [[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];
managedObjectRequestOperation.managedObjectContext = managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
[managedObjectRequestOperation setWillMapDeserializedResponseBlock:^id(id deserializedResponseBody) {
    return [deserializedResponseBody allValues];
}];
[[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] addOperation:managedObjectRequestOperation];
```